# Why is jQuery trying to load my scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a webpage with jQuery linked to the website.
Problem is, for some reason jQuery is trying to load my scripts.

This is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Inloggen | Andalusier Vereniging</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/prefixes.css" media="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/loginstyle.min.css" media="screen">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="../js/assets/checks.js" charset="utf-8"></script> -->
  <script src="lksdfj" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

  <body>



  </body>
</html>
```

Outputs: [image]

Now without the jQuery script (commented):
[image]

**EDIT:**
Alright, I just realised that the font link (@import) in the second CSS file is doing this. If I remove it, it stops executing twice. Any further ideas?

**FINAL EDIT:**
Thank you everyone for helping me clarify this problem. As a summary: Some browser tend to re-check if a file is found, but it will in no way execute the file twice.

So.. What is going on here, and should I worry about this?

Great thanks to the person that can provide me a good answer!

Comment: `<script src="lksdfj" type="text/javascript"></script>` doesn't look suspicious to you? It's not jQuery doing it.. you wrote that.

Comment: @Mjh He meant that it's loaded twice, when there's also jQuery loaded.

Comment: Gerrit, I don't think it's jQuery's issue. When I run your code (Firefox), it for some reason just sometimes retries to load not found scripts.

Comment: Ive noticed issues in the past with the console logging if i have it closed then open to view old logs. I wouldn't use the console anyway to confirm or deny requests, look in the network tab.

Comment: I can't get this error to happen on my end, what browser are you using?

Comment: @dragoste I had that possiblity in my mind, but what else could be wrong?

Comment: @ste2425 The thing is, it is completely random. Sometimes it does show twice in the Network tab, sometimes it does not.

Comment: @Theraot http://whatsmybrowser.org/b/F6UM8A1

Comment: @GerritLuimstra I have the same browser version and operating system. Running from file seem to be no problem. Running from Apache I got it to happen. I did try running the code without jquery, reloading a lot of times, it did eventually happen that it were loading the script twice. Adding jquary makes it happen all the time. Yet, it is not loading from jquery code. I'm guessing it is some buffer / cache issue. Tested Chrome (happens), Firefox (Happens), IE (doesn't happen), Edge (doesn't happen).

Comment: If the file exists, the browsers will load it once. So, this shouldn't be a problem in practice.

Comment: The moral of the story is no unlinked files in your html please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a 2 times file load (I mean that the jQuery dont try to run the file a 2nd time), its the same error 2 times.

Browsers opens many tcp connections with the server and pull the files needed for the page to render. So the browser knows then a file is missing before he need to run it.

And here is my point. Let us have 2 existing files, "xm.html" and "exist.js" (xm from xmmmm :P)
and a file that not exists, lets call it "dont_exist.js".

So the "xm.html" code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test Html</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">console.log('Execute code 1');</script>

        <script src="exist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">console.log('Execute code 3');</script>

        <script src="dont_exist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">console.log('Execute code 5');</script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the code of "exist.js" is

```
console.log('Execute code 2');
```

So my chrome's output is :

[image]

The error is in the possition the file's js code was going to be executed.

But firefox some times outputs this :

[image]

So the first error is the 404 error that the file was not found, but because firefox tried to run the file in the right order a while later, the same message was printed for debugging propuses I suppose.

**Edit**
Let me explain some more.
It depends on how the browser handles the files,

jQuery is not on your server so the browser need 2 or more tcp connections to load the files, over a tcp connection, the browser can make many http requests sequentially.

So the browser try to get as much files he needs as posible fast, by preloading them, not running them.

The jQuery file may takes more time to be downloaded while the other files wait.

So, when he cant find a file an error 404 appear, but, he may try to load it again if it thinks that the file was not preloaded (it costs nothing if the tcp connection is still running).

In no case does the browser run the file 2 times.

Comment: Put your script files above jquery script file. Then they will be loaded only  once.

Comment: Look: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UC50S.png - I have it appear twice in the Network tab, with different times. It is two attempt to load the file.

Comment: The tcp connection with the server is "Keep-Alive" the browser can ask again just to be sure that the file indeed does not exist, but this has nothing to do with the jQuery.
If no there is no other script above it, it does not preload it.